# Laravel 4 blade drop-down list class attribute

Tags: laravel, html-select, laravel-blade

Laravel blade drop down list class attribute not working.

I cannot find any reference to class or assigning attributes to select / drop-down lists in the documentation.

http://www.laravel.com/docs/html#drop-down-lists

Examples tried:

```
{{ Form::select('product_id', $productList, array('class'=>'form-control')) }}

{{ Form::select('product_id', $productList, $attributes = array('class'=>'form-control')) }}
```

Both return the same html but without the `class` attribute:

```
<select id="product_id" name="product_id">
    ... Option Stuff ...
</select>
```

Answer (score 75, accepted):

```
{{ Form::select('product_id', $productList, null, array('class' => 'form-control')) }}
```

The third parameter is the key of the currently selected option. Defaults to null.

Comment: Thanks for that... I wish that something as simple as this would be written in the documentation!!!

Comment: You can always check the source. If you are using sublime text hit `cmd + t` and type `FormBuilder`. Remember the framework is part of your application, just because you can't directly change the source code doesn't mean that you should not be familiar with the code in there.

Answer (score 0):

First get and create list in Controller for example:

```
$username_lists  = Users::lists('username','id');
```

pass data to view by:

```
 return View::make('layouts.customers')
            ->with('username_lists', $username_lists);
```

now get in view:

```
{{ Form::select('username_lists', $username_lists, null, array('class' => 'form-control')) }}
```