# laravel blade how to set the options for drop down list

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, laravel-blade

I am trying to create an drop down list using `blade`

I have already checked this question [Laravel 4 blade drop-down list class attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18530975/laravel-4-blade-drop-down-list-class-attribute)

I tried this:

```
 {{Form::select('category_id', $categories)}}
```

and the result is:

```
<select name="category_id"><option value="0">{"id":2,"name":"Apartment"}</option><option value="1">{"id":3,"name":"Car"}</option></select>
```

I couldn't know how to show just the `name` value of the options. plus I couldn't know how to set the value of each option to its `id`

I know the forth parameter is the option one, and I tried to do this

```
 {{Form::select('category_id', $categories, '', $categories)}}
```

but I got this exception:

```
htmlentities() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given (View:
```

please notice that the `$categories` is array, each row has `id` **and** `name`

#### Update 1

I send the value from controller to view like this

```
 $categories = Category::All(['id', 'name']);
```

where `Category` is a model

Comment: Please show how you get your values in $categories. It looks like you have JSON instead of an array in it.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29508297/laravel-5-how-to-populate-select-box-from-database-with-id-value-and-name-value/43039370#43039370

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`Form::select()` requires a flat array like

```
array(
  1 => 'Appartment',
  2 => 'Car'
)
```

whereas `$categories = Category::all()` gives you a multidimensional array that looks like

```
array(
  0 => array(
    'id' => 1,
    'name' => 'Appartment'
  ),
  1 => array(
    'id' => 2,
    'name' => 'Car'
  )
)
```

That being said just change

```
$categories = Category::all(['id', 'name']);
```

to

```
$categories = Category::lists('name', 'id');
```

Then this will work just fine

```
{{ Form::select('category_id', $categories) }}
```

Comment: first of all thank you. second where is the official documentation for that. lastly, I got this `<option value="Apartment">2</option>` I should have got this `<option value="2">Apartment</option>`, how to fix that please? +1

Comment: It seems that you reversed parameters in `lists()`. Take a closer look it should go `'name', 'id'` not vice versa. As far as the documentation is concerned take a look at http://laravel.com/docs/queries#selects. Specifically 'Retrieving A List Of Column Values'.