# How do I store the relation between models in db? - Laravel

Tags: eloquent, laravel-5, relationships

I have an employees table and a roles table. On the from to create an employee I also wish to assign a role. However my code stores the data with NULL on the foreign key in employees table. How do I make it store the relation?

Employees model.php

```
 class employees extends Model
{
     protected $fillable = [
     'first_name',
     'surname',
     ];

    public function Roles()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Roles');
    }
```

Roles model.php

```
class Roles extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = [
    'role_name',
    ];

    public function Employees()
    {
   return $this->hasMany('App\Employees');
    }
}`
```

Controller to create employee

```
 public function store(EmployeesRequest $request)
{
     $employee = Employees::find($request); 
    Employees::create($request->all());
    Roles::create($request->all());
    $employee->roles()->save($roles);
    return redirect()->route('employees.index')->with('message','Employee has been added'); 

}
```

On the form I have first_name, surname and role_name. These are saved but with NULL on the role_id column in my employees table? Tried reading the laravel docs but struggling to use ->save method

Current error it is returning is Call to a member function roles() on null

Answer (score 0):

You have to make the role_id fillable in your Employee Model:

```
protected $fillable = [
     'role_id', 
     'first_name',
     'surname',
     ];
```

In your Controller:
You need **use App\Roles;**

```
public function create()
    {   
        $role = Role::lists('role_name', 'id'); 
        return view('roles.create', compact('role'));

    }

 public function store(EmployeesRequest $request)
    { 
        Employees::create($request->all());
        return redirect()->route('employees.index')->with('message','Employee has been added'); 
    }
```

Form:

```
<div class="form-group">
            {!! Form::label('role_id', 'Role:') !!}
            {!! Form::select('role_id', $role, null, ['class' => 'form-control']) !!}
        </div>
```

HTML-Form:
Try something like this, I hope it works its not tested

```
<label>Role</label>
<select name="role_id">
  @foreach($roles as $role)
    <option value="{{ $role->id }}">{{ $role->role_name }}</option>
  @endforeach
</select
```

In your Controller:

```
public function create()
    {   
        $roles = Role::all();    
        return view('roles.create', compact('roles'));

    }
```

Comment: I have added 'roles_id' as fillable in the employees model.
The data for the employee is passing to the db however the role is no longer passing which is why I had 'Roles::create($request->all());'
When i do it either way 'role_id' is not populating to show a relationship. 

In the controller is there a syntax I should include to make it associate the role_id?
At the moment I am here but still no luck:
$employee = new Employees();
  Employees::create($request->all());
  
  Roles::create($request->all());
  $roles = $employee->roles()-> associate($employee);
  return redirect()->

Comment: Do you have the foreign key role_id field in the employee table? Do you have role_id  in the Employeesrequest?

Comment: Yes employees table has 'roles_id' and no EmpoyeesRequest did. I have just tested it with it in and roles_id column is still NULL

Comment: thanks that's great.
I am not using form collective. How do i render the above in proper html form?

Comment: I found a better answer in Stackoverflow to the form for you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29508297/laravel-5-how-to-populate-select-box-from-database-with-id-value-and-name-value