# Laravel pluck Array to string conversion

Tags: php, laravel, pluck

I am create complaint For that while inserting department for their complaint  I am using pluck() method to retrieve data from department table and display complaint in select dropdown as array but the problem is it is not working as it says

> Array to string conversion (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\test\resources\views\complaint\create.blade.php)

ComplaintController

```
 $department = Department::pluck('name','id')->all();

    return view('complaint.create',compact('department'));
```

create.blade.php

```
<strong>Department : </strong>
{!! Form::select('dep_id',$department,null,['class'=>'form-control']) !!}
```

Please help!

Comment: Department::pluck('name','id'); try this

Comment: this same error "Array to string conversion"

Comment: $department->toArray() use this in your view

Comment: array:2 [▼
  1 => "IT"
  2 => "HK"
]

Comment: Check this question : https://stackoverflow.com/q/29508297/2815635

Comment: I wrote this question. But i'm error ,i'm don't understand

Comment: Please try dd($department); and paste output in your question

Comment: you can't `pluck` two fields & show them in dropdown box, instead pluck one field & use it to populate dropbox.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it is not working try this:-

```
$department = Department::select('id','name')->get();
return view('complaint.create')->with(compact('department'));
```

Now your view like this:-

```
<strong>Department : </strong>
<select class="form-control" name="any-name">
@foreach($department as $dept)
 <option value="{{$dept->id}}">{{$dept->name}}</option>
@endforeach
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: Department table having data and echo all data see its coming or not?

Comment: this data from dd($department) 
array:2 [▼
  1 => "IT"
  2 => "HK"
]

Comment: Now try to compact on that blade file see my code how i compact

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/159883/discussion-between-kunal-and-story-ks).

Answer (score -1):

```
{!! Form::select('dep_id',$department,old('dep_id'),['class'=>'form-control', 'placeholder'=>'Select Any name']) !!}
```